# How do I add new row in Excel *below* the current one?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

The *Insert > Insert Sheet Rows* command in Excel always inserts a row **above** the current row. However, it is quite a common scenario for me to want to insert a row **below** the current row, like this:

[image]

The important detail is that the border was pushed down and that the formula was updated to include 3 cells instead of the original two. When I do it naively, by placing the cursor at the totals line and add a row there, I get this:

[image]

The border and formula are "broken" here and I need to fix them manually. What are my options?

*Note*: A "table" (Ctrl+T) would help with this but in my case, I need a generic solution that does not depend on the rows being part of a table.

Answer (score 1):

If you place your cursor on the row you want to insert below, [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/48974-insert-row-below.html) will do that and copy the format of that row:

> ```
> Sub InsertRowBelow()
>
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
>     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
>     ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
>     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
>     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
>         SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
>     Application.CutCopyMode = False
>
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
>
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Any solution without a macro?